# Get only month and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch only month and year from a date column in SQL Server.

Example: if today's date is `02/03/2019`, then I want `0319`.

**Note**: I want the result in same order (2 digit month and 2 digit year). Zero should not be removed from month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you could go for:

```
RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),DateColumn,3),'/',''),4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a number using:

```
select month(datecol) * 100 + (year(datecol) % 100)
```

Prepending the zeros requires a bit more work:

```
select right('0' + convert(varchar(255), month(datecol) * 100 + (year(datecol) % 100)), 4)
```

Or, you can use `format()`:

```
select format(datecol, 'MMyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
substring(convert(nvarchar,@date,12),3,2) + left(convert(nvarchar,@date,12),2)
```

You can create an user defined function, and then apply to your column/s

```
create function udf_Getmonthyear(@date as date)
RETURNS nchar(4)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @d_format nchar(6) = (select convert(nvarchar,@date,12))

    RETURN (select SUBSTRING(@d_format,3,2) + left(@d_format,2)) 
end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function `DATEPART` in TSQL to get any part of a `DateTime` value. e.g:

`DATEPART(yy,datecol)` gives you 4 digit year part of a `DateTime` column (e.g: `datecol`), using the `%` (modulus) operator you can get 2 digit year `DATEPART(yy,datecol)%100`.
`DATEPART(mm,datecol)` gives you month part of the `datecol` field.

```
select Right('0'+cast(DATEPART(mm,datecol) as varchar(2)),2) +
       Right('0'+cast(DATEPART(yy,datecol)%100 as varchar(2)),2) MonthYearPart
from MyTable
```

Regards